# User Update Test in the Junit Doesn't Work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying make a test to Update User method that first get a User by id and after update the user , work it, but when I try to make a test in the Junit show me that couldn't find the user by Id. Can anyone help me, please?

**UserClass**

```
package br.com.projectsmanagement.entities;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataCadastro;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String password, Date dataCadastro) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getDataCadastro() {
        return dataCadastro;
    }

    public void setDataCadastro(Date dataCadastro) {
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
    }
}
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
@Override
    public User updateUser(Long id, User user) {
        try {
            User userUpdated = userRepository.findById(id).get();
            userUpdated.setName(user.getName());
            userUpdated.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            return userRepository.saveAndFlush(userUpdated);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new InvalidIdException("Usuário não encontrado!");
        }
    }
```

And finally my **UserServiceImplTest**

```
package br.com.projectsmanagement.services.impl;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import br.com.projectsmanagement.entities.User;
import br.com.projectsmanagement.exception.EmailExistException;
import br.com.projectsmanagement.repositories.UserRepository;

@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private User user;
    private Optional<User> optionalUser;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        startUser();
    }

    @Test
    void whenFindAllThenReturnAnListofUsers() {
        when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(List.of(user));

        List<User> response = userServiceImpl.listUsers();

        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(1, response.size());
        assertEquals(User.class, response.get(0).getClass());
    }

    @Test
    void whenFindByIdThenReturnAnUserInstance() {
        when(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(optionalUser);

        Optional<User> response = userServiceImpl.getUserById(1L);

        assertThat(response).isPresent();
        assertEquals(optionalUser.getClass(), response.getClass());
        assertEquals(optionalUser.get().getName(), "Valdir");
    }

    @Test
    void whenRegisterThenReturnSuccess() {
        when(userRepository.saveAndFlush(any())).thenReturn(user);

        User response = userServiceImpl.registerUser(user);

        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(User.class, response.getClass());
        assertEquals(user.getId(), response.getId());
    }

    @Test
    void whenRegisterThenReturnAnEmailExistException() {
        when(userRepository.findByEmail(anyString())).thenReturn(user);

        try {
            userServiceImpl.registerUser(user);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            assertEquals(EmailExistException.class, e.getClass());
            assertEquals("Esse e-mail já está cadastrado!", e.getMessage());
        }

        User response = userServiceImpl.registerUser(user);

        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(User.class, response.getClass());
        assertEquals(user.getId(), response.getId());
    }

    @Test
    void whenUpdateThenReturnSuccess() {
        when(userRepository.saveAndFlush(any())).thenReturn(user);

        User response = userServiceImpl.updateUser(1L, user);

        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(User.class, response.getClass());
    }

    @Test
    void testDeleteUser() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private void startUser() {
        user = new User("Valdir", "valdir@gmail.com", "123456", new Date());
        optionalUser = Optional.of(new User("Valdir", "valdir@gmail.com", "123456", new Date()));
    }
}
```

I modified my class many times, but even doesn't work it

Comment: In the test class there are many method. Can you please share which method is not working ?

Comment: It's whenUpdateThenReturnSuccess method

Answer (score 0):

I think in your test case whenUpdateThenReturnSuccess(), you forgot to mock the userRepository.findById(id) that you call when updating your user.

If not mocked, it returns null.

```
@Test
void whenUpdateThenReturnSuccess() {
    when(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(optionalUser);
    when(userRepository.saveAndFlush(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);

    User response = userServiceImpl.updateUser(1L, user);

    assertNotNull(response);
    assertEquals(User.class, response.getClass());
}
```